# AGPL-3.0 license

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing, open-source-software

If make a service for a open source software with this license that interact but isn't part of the software itself, only connected to it,

i would need to provide a open source distribution of the connector/modifications on the software itself, right?

but do i also need to make my service code open source (in this case my server, which doesn't use the software)?

for example:

Imagine there is a open source excel/calculator available under AGPL-3.0 and i make a plugin to integrate in my service which would be like Dropbox, One Drive, Google  drive & etc... to automatically save/sync my customer files used by the open source software. Like those examples, my server wouldn't provide services only for users using this software

In this case i would need to make available the code for connecting to my service (like how it detect changes and upload files to Dropbox)

But would i need to make open source, my server? which doesn't use any of open source code, only interacts with it, via modifications done on the user software?

Comment: From you question I cannot figure out exactly what you will be doing, and what "does not use, but interacts with" means in practice.  It is likely that the details of this link will determine if the server code is a derivative work of the OS code.

Comment: fair enough, imagine you have an open source app to edit photos, and i want to create a service to store the photos on the cloud, there is 2 ways i can go about it, create a software to check the folder where photos are saved as a independent software and sync, or the other option : modify the software to make a Sync with X button, the software was modified to communicate with the server, but the server itself has nothing to do with the app itself, it only stores the photos and let you access anywhere, Would my server code also be subject to the license? no, right?